# How to compile two conflict 3rd library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-linking

I am maintaining an iOS project which used PhoneGap library, which uses an open source file named Reachability(Reachability.h & Reachability.m). Now I want to add BPush library to the project. Sadly the BPush also needs Reachability. However, the two Reachability file are different. How can I add them into one project?

Comment: Any problems re-naming files and fixing #include/#import detectives a bit?

Comment: @Gobra I don't have the source codes of the two libraries so I can not use the re-naming solution.

Comment: How about using CocoaPods?

Comment: But I don't want to add more libraries into the project, because it's a very old project, and lots of changes will probably cause uncertain problem.